# reject validations and cast_association if nested attribute is nil

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, nested-attributes

Is there a way in phoenix changeset to reject nested attributes and not cast or validate the attrs if the nested attrs are all nil?

I am looking for the equivalent of rails 

`accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses, reject_if: :all_blank`

This should not return validation errors on addresses and still allow persistence of the unnested parameters. I would expect email and first_name to still be saved while addresses to be ignored.

```
# Example attrs 
%{"addresses" => %{"0" => %{"address_type" => nil, "city" => nil, "street1" => nil, "street2" => nil}}, email: "info@gmail.com",  first_name: "dave"}


@user [:email, first_name]
def user_changeset(%User{} = user, attrs \\ %{}) do
  user
  |> cast(attrs, @user)
  |> validate_required(@user)
  |> validate_format(:email, ~r/@/)
  |> cast_assoc(:addresses, required: false, with: &addresses_from_changeset/2)
end 

@address [:city, :street1, :address_type]
defp addresses_from_changeset(model, params \\ :empty) do
  model
  |> cast(params, @address_fields)
  |> validate_required(@address_fields)
end
```

Comment: Looks like there isn't a good solution for this yet: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/elixir-ecto/ScPo16tfllc. A possible workaround includes manually removing such blank entries from `attrs` before passing the data to `cast` and `cast_assoc`.